# Automatic Versioning in TFS Build

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, msbuild, versioning

I am not sure whether i can the problem good explaning. Well we use TFS for our building. And in our VS solution, there is also an installshield setup project.

Well, sometimes our team members forget the increase products' versions that why we want to give the version number automatically generated like **3.7.1.***
so when we build the project, the version of our product dll/exe will be 3.7.1.5655

and let say we've created the following versions

```
3.7.1.1234
3.7.1.5678
3.7.1.9134
```

and we gave the product Version 3.7.1.5678 to our customer. And after a while, the customer said that there is a bug in this version and the version number is 3.7.1.5678.

So, as I said earlier, we made the version number format like **3.7.1.*** and we commit always like that so the assemblyinfo.cs file will not be changed. and when the customer said that the  version 3.7.1.5678 has problem. how can we find the related version what the customer has, in tfs commit. Let say we committed several time in the same day and we cannot see (or i dont know it) where the version number 3.7.1.5678 has been stored.

Well, I need to find the realted commit and work on this time project but i dont cannot know which commit it was.

My question is that how you solve this problem?

I hope i could explain it.

We have TFS Version 16.122.26918.3 and we use mostly Visual Studio 2017

Comment: Hi ertan2002, any update on this, did my workaround do the trick?

Comment: Hello Patrick, I've solved this with another way.I've created a powershell script. This script automatically increases the version number by reading assemblyinfo.cs and then commit-push to git. After that I start to build steps and it build the project with the increased number. This is useful for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could find the **corresponding build** of version number which is 3.7.1.5678.

For a particular build, it's easy to get related changeset/commit.

Then you could pull down that changeset/commit from TFS to your local workspace, and work on the bugs.

Not sure what your build number looks like, it's better to make a part of build number the same as the last version number(5678), like the usage of $(BuildID).

`$(BuildID)` is an internal immutable ID.

Comment: Your answer seems also correct for this case. I accept it as the answer. Thank you for your attention.